# Spring mvc- thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I want to multiply the two values but unable to do it as it thrown error,
I am new to thymeleaf template and trying to multiply item price and quantity.

Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: `#aggregates.sum.![p.item.price * p.orderQuantity]` `(cart:49)`.

Please help me to multiply the two number using thymeleaf template.

Comment: <tr th:each="p, iterStat :${session.itemList}"> <td th:text="${p.item.price}"></td>
   <td th:text="${p.orderQuantity}"></td>
      <td th:text="${#aggregates.sum[p.item.price * p.orderQuantity]}"/> 
   
  </tr>

Comment: Above comment is my html code.. Please help

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
${#aggregates.sum(p.item.{price * orderQuantity})}
```